# Android - Why does UI Object reference becomes null when returning from adapter call?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having a WTF moment today.

Consider the following code snippet in an Android fragment -:

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), points_array_list);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

//When returning from adapter a particular UI object(ie. a TextView) becomes //null

for(Point p : points_array_list) {
if (p.getTextView() == null) {
                Log.wtf("WTF","Why is it NULL ?");
            }
}
```

In the adapter the code is as follows -:

```
TextView view = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.point_textview);

point.setView(view);
```

Both the adapter and fragment share the same `ArrayList<Point>` reference.

Now the reason I am doing this is because I have to update the TextView on an event.

Can anyone tell me why does it become null after it returns from the adapter call ?

Also please note I have added the following check to make sure it is not null there -:

```
if(point.getCoordView() != null) {
                Log.wtf("WTF", "Its not null");
            }
```

And the above sanity check works as expected but the object still becomes null when I return from the adapter.

Comment: What do you mean by "returning from adapter call"? What method does the second snippet come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results in adapter need to a few milliseconds for initializing. You can use this

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               for(Point p : points_array_list) {
                if (p.getTextView() == null) {
                  Log.wtf("WTF","Why is it NULL ?");
                  }
                }
             }
        }, 500);
```

Comment: Looks like a race condition to me.